# Uploading file on Prestashop order page

Tags: image, upload, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

uploaded the module in the link below in my prestashop 1.6.1.7 but unfortunaly I can't find it in the list of modules.

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/456742-free-module-file-upload-let-customers-upload-other-files-besides-images/

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you see a folder "modules/fileupload/" in your site?

Comment: No, I don't see it. It mentions that the module is successfuly uploaded but I can't find it

Comment: Upload module folder directly from FTP. Them you will find it in your backoffice list.

Comment: I also tried this one under "/www/themes/biomagic/modules" but nothing I can't find it

Comment: How are you trying to install your module? FTP, Prestashop backoffice?

Comment: I tried it from the backoffice, it didn't work. So? Itried the FTP and no result too.

Comment: The correct folder is `/www/modules/`, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all make sure that after unzip this module you have directory called `fileupload` (it is very important)
2. Then upload this folder through FTP to directory `/modules` not `/themes/<theme_name>/modules`
3. Go to your modules in backoffice and make sure you don't have any filters like "show only installed and active" etc.
4. Your module name is "fileupload" so on the list should be module with this name
5. Install and enjoy :)